# Some metadata doesn't show up in manually created .shp.xml in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, metadata

I'm creating shapefiles in Python using geopandas from processed climatological information. This a simplified version of the code I'm using to generate the shapefiles:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

#Creating square polygons
center_lat = -20
center_lon = -50
side_length = 2
squares = []
for i in range(5): 
    top_left = (center_lon + (i * side_length), center_lat + (side_length / 2))
    top_right = (center_lon + ((i + 1) * side_length), center_lat + (side_length / 2))
    bottom_right = (center_lon + ((i + 1) * side_length), center_lat - (side_length / 2))
    bottom_left = (center_lon + (i * side_length), center_lat - (side_length / 2))
    
    square = Polygon([top_left, top_right, bottom_right, bottom_left])
    squares.append(square)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=squares)

#Random values
gdf['val'] = [20, 30, 25, 18, 22]
gdf['sigma'] = [5, 7, 4, 6, 8]

gdf.to_file('squares.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

And they look something like this:

```
gdf
Out[27]: 
                                            geometry  val  sigma
0  POLYGON ((-50.00000 -19.00000, -48.00000 -19.0...   20      5
1  POLYGON ((-48.00000 -19.00000, -46.00000 -19.0...   30      7
2  POLYGON ((-46.00000 -19.00000, -44.00000 -19.0...   25      4
3  POLYGON ((-44.00000 -19.00000, -42.00000 -19.0...   18      6
4  POLYGON ((-42.00000 -19.00000, -40.00000 -19.0...   22      8
```

I've tried manually creating a `.shp.xml` file using [this ESRI metadata example](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/main/modules/plugin/shapefile/src/test/resources/org/geotools/data/shapefile/test-data/example.shp.xml). I just copied the file to the same folder as `squares.shp`, and saved it to `squares.shp.xml`. When I open `squares.shp` in QGIS (v. 3.34.1), some of the metadata show up in the information tab/metadata tab but some fields are missing:

[image: QGIS information]

[image: QGIS information 2]

For example, the abstract and contact show but the citation information doesn't show. If I add a random title to the `<descript>` section under `<idinfo>`, like so:

```
    <idinfo>
        <native Sync="TRUE">Windows NT Version 5.0 (Build 2195) ; ESRI ArcInfo 8.1.0.515</native>
        <descript>
            <langdata Sync="TRUE">en</langdata>
            <title>A title</title>
            <abstract>Metadata sample document</abstract> 
            <purpose>Provides a sample of the information that can be parsed</purpose> 
        </descript>
        ...
    </idinfo>
```

it doesn't show up either. I don't have ArcGIS so I can't use ArcPy to create the `xml` file.

Any ideas in what could be the problem?